# loop for table generation with pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplots, macros, pgfplotstable, csv

I am using `pgfplotstable` to enter my CSV tables into LaTeX. The issue is that I am using two lines as the header, in the first line introducing my variables and second line their units. 
The following `MWE` works perfectly fine for my goal, but what annoys me is that I have to repeat `every row #1 column 0/.append style={#2}`
so many times to assure that with entering a table with an arbitrary number of columns This code will still work. I was trying to put this line in a loop, but even with checking questions here and other sources I failed every time.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

 \usepackage{filecontents}

 \begin{filecontents*}{mytable.csv}
  Number,$\mathrm{f}$,$\Delta\mathrm{f}$
  ,\si{\kHz},\si{\kHz}
  1,1000,0.1
  2,3000,0.2
  3,5000,0.3
 \end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,array,pgfgantt, 
 pgfplots,colortbl,gensymb,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotstableset{
rowstyle/.style 2 args={
    every row #1 column 0/.append style={#2},
    every row #1 column 1/.append style={#2},
    every row #1 column 2/.append style={#2},
    every row #1 column 3/.append style={#2},
    every row #1 column 4/.append style={#2},     
},
colstyle/.style 2 args={
every col no #1/.append style={#2}, 
},
header=false, 
col sep = comma,
every head row/.style={output empty row},
every first row/.style={before row=\toprule},   
every row no 1/.style ={after row=\midrule},
every even row/.style={before row=\rowcolor{lightgray}},
rowstyle={0}{string type},
rowstyle={1}{string type},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
    fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=3,
    columns/0/.append style={precision=0},
    ]
    {mytable.csv}
    \caption{Caption of my table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

So, in the end, I have two questions:

1. Assuming I am entering a large number as maximum columns number(for example 50) how can I put it in a loop that I do not have to repeat it 50 times?
2. Is there any way to have a macro which goes through the CSV file, checks the number of columns and makes a loop for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an option, which sets the `first 2 rows as string`? But it must be used after every thing, which sets the cell type with `string type`, `numeric type` etc., or it will be overwritten. The advantage: no need to know how many columns there are.

This uses `.add code` to wrap the original code of `assign cell content` into the `\else` part of an `\ifcase`, which checks the row number (`\pgfplotstablerow`) and sets the cell content for the first 2 rows to the raw input instead of the formated number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

 \usepackage{filecontents}

 \begin{filecontents*}{mytable.csv}
  Number,$\mathrm{f}$,$\Delta\mathrm{f}$
  ,\si{\kHz},\si{\kHz}
  1,1000,0.1
  2,3000,0.2
  3,5000,0.3
 \end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,array,pgfgantt, 
 pgfplots,colortbl,gensymb,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotstableset{
% must be used after everything setting type (string type, numeric type, etc.),
% otherwise it will be overwritten
first 2 rows as string/.style={%
    assign cell content/.add code={%
        % prepend to original code
        \ifcase\pgfplotstablerow
            % row 0: take raw contents
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1}%
        \or
            % row 1: take raw contents
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1}%
        \else
            % other rows: original code
    }{%
        % append to original code
        \fi
    }%
},
colstyle/.style 2 args={
every col no #1/.append style={#2}, 
},
header=false, 
col sep = comma,
every head row/.style={output empty row},
every first row/.style={before row=\toprule},   
every row no 1/.style ={after row=\midrule},
every even row/.style={before row=\rowcolor{lightgray}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
    fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=3,
    columns/0/.append style={precision=0},
    first 2 rows as string
    ]
    {mytable.csv}
    \caption{Caption of my table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```